# How to put conditions in $lt within aggregation-pipeline?

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I want to filter my data on the basis of item in the group stage such that, item equals 'report' then the comparison should have to `$lt: ['createdAt', 3]` and if 'history' it should be `$lt: ['createdAt', 5]`. Considering i have many items apart from report and history. How to achieve it in pipeline?

Here is my sample collection data:

```
[
  {
    s3Url: 1,
    item: "report",
    sid: "x",
    createdAt: 4,
    
  },
  {
    s3Url: 2,
    item: "report",
    sid: "x",
    createdAt: 3,
    
  },
  {
    s3Url: 3,
    item: "report",
    sid: "y",
    createdAt: 2,
    
  },
  {
    s3Url: 4,
    item: "history",
    sid: "x",
    createdAt: 8,
    
  },
]
```

Here is my attempt:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      sid: "x"
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$item",
      s3Urls: {
        $push: {
          $cond: [
            {
              $lt: [
                "$createdAt",
                5
              ]
            },
            "$s3Url",
            "$$REMOVE"
          ]
        }
      },
      
    }
  },
])
```

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, let's put a switch here.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      sid: "x"
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      s3Url: 1,
      item: 1,
      sid: 1,
      createdAt: 1,
      expiry: {
        "$switch": {
          "branches": [
            {
              "case": {
                "$eq": [
                  "$item",
                  "report"
                ]
              },
              "then": 4
            },
            {
              "case": {
                "$eq": [
                  "$item",
                  "report"
                ]
              },
              "then": 5
            }
          ],
          "default": 10
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$item",
      s3Urls: {
        $push: {
          $cond: [
            {
              $lt: [
                "$createdAt",
                "$expiry"
              ]
            },
            "$s3Url",
            "$$REMOVE"
          ]
        }
      },
      
    }
  },
])
```